# Identify Simultaneous Notes in Different Streams

Tags: python, music21

I'd like to determine when notes from two different parts/instruments should be played at the same moment.

[image: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1280/7719/products/Air_on_the_G_String_Preview.jpg?v=1464908099]

Take the above sheet music. In the third measure, the treble clef's accented A and the bass clef's B should be played in unison. How can I parse a music21 stream and find all these instances?

I know that each 'part' of a piece can be parsed in the order of its notes with:

```
numParts = len(piece.parts)
for i in range(numParts):
    part = piece.parts[i].flat.notesAndFlats
    for note in part:
        #will access each note or chord in the part sequentially
```

But this doesn't allow me to determine when a note in part one starts at the same moment as a note in part 2.

Answer (score 0):

iterate through offset each part. But take in account that there are a lot of notes which will not match and also for every note there usually is different length.

```
oiter = stream.iterator.OffsetIterator(parts[0])
for groupedElements in oiter:
    print(groupedElements, groupedElements[0].quarterLength, groupedElements[0].offset)
```

Later check if those parts have the same offsets. If they have then those notes are played at the same time.